# How to implement Google Campaign Measurement of google analytics in react native android?

Tags: android, react-native, google-analytics, google-analytics-campaign-builder

How can I implement **Google Campaign Measurement using react native** .

I am trying to follow this guide: 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns

Steps I am taking

1. Add the Google Analytics receiver to your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<application>
    <!-- Used for Google Play Store Campaign Measurement-->
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
</application>
```

2. Broadcasting an INSTALL_REFERRER Intent

```
$ cd <path_to_adb_tool>
$ echo 'am broadcast \
    -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER \
    -n "your.package.name/path.to.receiver" \
    --es "referrer" \
      "utm_source=test_source&utm_medium=test_medium&utm_term=test_term&utm_content=test_content&utm_campaign=test_name"; \
    exit' | ./adb shell
```

3. Verifying the Campaign Data Was Received- not able to receive this below line in adb output
   `GAv4    : Received installation campaign: source=testSource`

Is there any extra step I need to do for react native with react-native-firebase?

Comment: Same problem. Did you find an answer?